# How to make custom video controller even in full-screen in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

My question is how to make a custom control system with an HTML5 video element in angular. I always follow StackOverflow and I got always great solutions with you sir but for this question, I didn't get the perfect solution. It's a humble request please give me some solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer to my question. So I'm posting this.

HTML code

```
<video #videoTag id="videoId" playsinline controls poster="{{imageName}}" preload="metadata" width="100%" height="250">
Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
<div id="video-controller-id" class="video-controller" fx fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
    <div>
        <mat-slide-toggle checked={{isToggle}} (change)="toggle($event)">{{isPlay}}
        </mat-slide-toggle>
    </div>
    <div fxLayout="row">
        <div fxLayout="row" class="volume">
            <mat-icon matTooltip="{{muteStatus}}" matTooltipHideDelay="500" matTooltipPosition="above" style="cursor: pointer; color: white;" (click)="videoVolume()">
                {{volume}}
            </mat-icon><input #volumeSlider class="volume-slider" id="volumeSlider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" step="1" (input)="videoVolumeSlider(volumeSlider.value)">
        </div>
        <div>
            <mat-icon style="cursor: pointer; color: white;" (click)="fullScreen()">fullscreen
            </mat-icon>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

TypeScript code for fullscreen

```
 fullScreen() {
    this.myVideo = document.getElementById("video");
    this.videoContainer = document.getElementById("video-container-id");

    if (document.fullscreenElement) {
      document.exitFullscreen();
      this.myVideo.style.height = "250px";
      this.myVideo.style.width = "100%";
    } else {
      this.videoContainer.requestFullscreen();
      this.videoTag.nativeElement.style.height = "100%";
      this.videoTag.nativeElement.style.width = "100%";
    }
  }
```